# Keycloak custom provider with Quarkus extension - where to put quarkiverse jars as dependencies?

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I'm writing custom Keycloak provider which needs [quarkus-cxf](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cxf) extension as a dependency to integrate with a SOAP service. Everything works well in the development mode (I use maven, so I needed to add quarkus-cxf as a dependency and run Keycloak on Quarkus from IDE using [IDELauncher](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/quarkus/server/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quarkus/_private/IDELauncher.java)).

The problem starts when I'm trying to deploy my custom provider to the production environment. I know that my provider's jar need to be placed in `providers` directory within Keycloak distribution. Somewhere on Keycloak webpage I saw that every third-party dependencies jars I use, need to be placed in `providers` directory as well, so I did that and (thanks to maven-dependency-plugin) I generated all [quarkus-cxf](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cxf) dependencies and put them all into `providers` directory. Then I tried to build keycloak by running `./kc.bat build` and it failed with the message: `ERROR: io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigFactory: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.QuarkusConfigFactory not a subtype`.

How it should be done to work properly? I need CXF dependencies in the build phase because I generate code from WSDL file and it's necessary for Quarkus augmentation. Maybe not all dependencies from [quarkus-cxf](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cxf) dependency hierarchy are needed here, but I cannot imagine developing and then adding one by one jar and check if it's enough for build or maybe not and I will get NoClassDefFound error :) I've got the same problem with my previous extension where I used resteasy dependencies but then only few jars were missing so I put them into `providers` directory and it worked. It's not the best solution for each and every one extension with extra dependencies like cxf (with huge hierarchy of transient dependencies).

Does anyone help me in this case? Maybe some of you have the same problem and you know how it should be done.

Comment: Hi - did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm in exactly the same position now with needing to add each dependency jar is 1 by 1 and its a nightmare. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi, for now we handled it by executing two plugins goals. First one is quarkus-maven-plugin and the goal dependency-tree - this goal shows us exactly those dependencies that are absolutely necessary to copy to the distribution and the other one is maven-dependency-plugin with goal copy-dependencies which generates ALL jars from dependency tree (also these that shouldn't be copied to the distribution package). Then we copy only those jars from the result of copy-dependency goal of maven-dependency-plugin that are present as a result of dependency-tree goal of quarkus-maven-plugin.

Comment: Obviously this quarkus-maven-plugin and the goal dependency-tree displays whole project dependency tree, so we copy only those under e.g. quarkus-cxf subtree.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/19630